# widget hiding under background when use image in background, no problem with color

Tags: flutter

I am getting trouble using flutter widget when set background image.
if I use color as background, then widget showing correctly, otherwise it only showing text of that widget, other widget  color goes under background image.

```
class SplashView extends StatelessWidget {
  const SplashView({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
      Positioned.fill(  
            child: Image(
                    image: AssetImage('assets/images/decent.jpg'),
                    fit : BoxFit.fill,
            ),
           // child: Container( color: Colors.amber)
          ), 
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 60, vertical: 12),
          child: Text(title,
                   style: TextStyle(
                   fontSize: 18,
                   color: Colors.white
                 ),
       ),
       decoration: BoxDecoration(
       color: primaryColor,
       borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
    ),
    );

      ],
    );
  }
```

}

[image: screen with background-color only]

Widget showing correctly here (Button showing background here)

[image: screen with background Image]

Here it only shows text of button widget, button background not showing.

NOTE* I am facing this problem on WEB.

Comment: What is the reason to use `Positioned.fill`?

Comment: @Blasanka Exactly

Comment: @Blasanka No reason, I tried other way also, but its not working. I am facing this problem on web.

Answer (score 0):

I run your code it is working without any Issue[image]
Just check with another Image asset, also uninstall the app and run the project again

Comment: Please run this code on WEB, I am developing for web platform.

Answer (score 0):

You should use like this

```
 class SplashView extends StatelessWidget {
  const SplashView({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[

            Image.asset(
          "assets/login_bg.png",
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
          ), 
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 60, vertical: 12),
          child: Text(title,
                   style: TextStyle(
                   fontSize: 18,
                   color: Colors.white
                 ),
       ),
       decoration: BoxDecoration(
       color: primaryColor,
       borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
    ),
    );

      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Several changes you can make like removing positioned filled to setting up 
Column with

```
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
```

and setting it's children inside it.